# Adding onto JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface

I was wondering if it was possible to add dropdown menus to a main JPanel from a different class instead of calling it from that class itself. Mainly because a friend and I are working on a personal project trying to create different programs in different tabs.

Here's our main GUI:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public GUI() {
        setTitle("Andy and Jack's favorite programs");
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        getContentPane().add(jtp);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();

        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

        jp1.add(label1);
        jtp.addTab("Andy - Encryption Program");
        jp2.add(label2);
        jtp.addTab("Andy - Hello World Program");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       GUI tp = new GUI();
       tp.setVisible(true);
       tp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
   }
```

Here's one of our tabs:

```
public class encryptionPrograms extends GUI {
    String[] options = new String[] { "XOR", "RSA" };
    ComboBox optionsList = new JComboBox(options);
    jp1.add(optionsList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly or not. Just got into Java and we've have been playing around with the GUI buttons and such.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of "wrong" here and without you saying what your intention is with adding a comboBox to your jPanel it's hard to tell you the right way to do it but yes it can be done.

But first of: Always declare your variables before you initialize them so that you can access them for other methods in the class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    private JPanel jp1,jp2;
    private JLabel label1,label2;
    private JTabbedPane jtp;

    public GUI() {
        setTitle("Andy and Jack's favorite programs");
        jtp = new JTabbedPane();

        jp1 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel();

        jp2 = new JPanel();
        label2 = new JLabel();

        jp1.add(label1);
        jtp.addTab("Andy - Encryption Program", jp1);
        jp2.add(label2);
        jtp.addTab("Andy - Hello World Program",jp2);

        getContentPane().add(jtp);
   }
```

If you need to access a variable from another class you can write a get method for it.

For example:

```
public JPanel getMainJPanel(){
       return jp1;
}
```

Now you can call the getMainJPanel() from another class in order to, for instance, add components to it. Just remember to `.revalidate()` and `.repaint()` the main **frame** after adding more components.